# Position:fixed in css: depending on scrollbar position, the div appears in a different position

Tags: javascript, html

I have a "loading" div with a GIF, that shows when the page starts to unLoad. It is position:fixed by CSS, and suposed to remain centered. The problem is that depending on where you are in the page when you trigger the event that shows the DIV, the position where it appears changes, the closest to the end of the page you are, more it moves. BUT it doesnt appear if you scroll down, it is like hidden in a non-visible part of the browser =/.

http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4580/ss1nn.jpg

http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7783/ss2df.jpg

Hope it is clear enough. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think the div was given `absolute` attrib. Try to look into it

Comment: @VivekChandra Have only the css code because the html is auto-generated by the application, here it is: http://pastebin.com/z7QY9eB9

Comment: use firebug and copy the auto generated code and then paste it.. else,how can u guess where u went wrong??

Comment: @VivekChandra Here is the HTML: http://pastebin.com/wQpemaQx
I'm a newby in web programing =(

Comment: no worries,we all had started sometime.. lol.. your css aswell..

Comment: The CSS is in my previous comment =P

PS. to add a little piece of pain, the browser must be IE8, but i have also tried in FF and the same happens, so it is not just IE magic smiling

Answer (score 0):

inorder to center an element -- do not use `position:fixed` use `position:relative` and add `margin: 0 auto;` the `0` is the `margin-top` which you can give as per your needs.

Comment: OK. i've tried it, and with position:relative the image wont show =(

Comment: Ok, now i've isolated the problem i think. The div with class Icon-wait is the one wich should have the img, not the one actually does. How can I select it if it has no id?